# Android: Подключение *.so библиотек Атол, в проект на AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

В доках пример по разработке приложения в Eclipse, всё работает. Переношу проект в AndroidStudio, не работает, не может найти библиотеки из *.so файлов! Пробовал все варианты, делал собственную JAR, создавал скрипт упаковки в Gradle, создавал папку и кидал туда *.so библиотеки, ничего не помогает, постоянно одно и то же сообщение:

```
10-16 13:18:38.030: W/dalvikvm(5101): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lcom/atol/drivers/fptr/IFptrNative;
10-16 13:18:38.030: W/dalvikvm(5101): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41869438)
10-16 13:18:38.050: E/AndroidRuntime(5101): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-16 13:18:38.050: E/AndroidRuntime(5101): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
10-16 13:18:38.050: E/AndroidRuntime(5101):     at com.atol.drivers.fptr.IFptr.create(IFptr.java:14)
10-16 13:18:38.050: E/AndroidRuntime(5101):     at ru.gc986.testprintserver.printlib.printers.Atol_11.<init>(Atol_11.java:26)
```

Ошибка происходит в момент создания объекта с помощью JAR библиотеки. Она в свою очередь тыкается в *.so файлы, но найти то что ей нужно не может. Кто виноват и что делать?

---

Решение подсказали на сайте Атола, объектники необходимо поместить в папку - app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi, а jar в папку - app/src/main/libs , и только тогда всё начинает работать!

Comment: Попробуйте создайт папку ```jniLibs``` в каталоге ```app\src\main``` если в ```build.gradle``` не указан другой путь, и положить туда .so либы.

Comment: Только что ещё раз попробовал как вы указали, но результат тот же.

Comment: я могу ошибаться, но Android Studio и gradle плохо дружат с NDK. Ркомендуют с ними работать пока еще из-под Eclipse

Comment: Дело в том что я не компилирую библиотеку, а пытаюсь подключить уже созданную. Тоже слышал что не сильно дружат, но я на днях обновил студию до 1.4, говорят с этой версии NDK уже адекватный должен быть.

Answer (score 1):

Надо положить `*.so` библиотеки разбив их по платформам `armeabi`, `mips` и `x86` в какой-нибудь каталог и указать путь к каталогу в gradle скрипте:

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }        
}
```

У меня так работает без вопросов.

Comment: Положил, указал, теперь новая ошибка:

`10-16 15:40:58.438: W/dalvikvm(6628): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41869438)
10-16 15:40:58.438: E/AndroidRuntime(6628): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-16 15:40:58.438: E/AndroidRuntime(6628): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load libfptr: findLibrary returned null`

Comment: Значит формат либы не нравится линкеру. Где вы ее вообще берете? Киньте ссылку.

Comment: На сайте Атол-а - http://www.atol.ru/link/file/699/


Там же и инструкция к ней - http://www.atol.ru/link/file/697/

Comment: Эта ссылка не помогает? [stackoverflow.com/questions/11872692](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872692/couldnt-load-libfoo-findlibrary-returned-null)

Comment: Сейчас попробую, но как я понимаю не должна помочь, так как производитель предоставляет JAR библиотеку которая сама обращается к *.so файлам, в своих внутренних функциях. Пересобрать JAR не получиться.

Comment: К сожалению не получилось.